# Suggestion Needed Formula or Worklfow

Tags: community, workflow, formula

What I am trying to do is whenever Lead Owner field is changed, a custom field on the lead object (Custom_field1__c) will be updated with Lead Owner Sales Level.  The Lead owner Sales level can be obtain on the user object (Sales_Level__c).

Can I achieve this with a formula or workflow?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a formal field on Lead

```
Owner:User.Sales_Level__c
```